# (Debain/Ubuntu-based Linux) How to access programs on /home partition after switching distros

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, home-folder

I recently switch from Lubuntu 18.04 to Peppermint OS 8, both of which are Debian/Ubuntu-Based. Before I did that, I made a `/home` partition and moved all my content for the root based `/home` folder to the partition one. Now that I have Peppermint OS installed, How can I access my programs from the Home folder?

Things to take note of:

- Peppermint OS detects the `/home` partition and uses it as a home folder
- No programs from the `/home` partition show up in the application menu

What should I do? Is it possible? Anything will help.

Comment: 1) check that you can start these programs from a terminal and that they still run (they could have dependencies not resolved on the new system). 2) create a `{application}.desktop` file for each of them (there must be an application menu editor somewhere in your system).

Comment: @xenoid Bad news, it will work, but most my programs will not start in the terminal. Only my RetroPie will start. But even that has some missing components. What should I do? Just reinstall the programs? Anything will do.

Comment: Yes, reinstalling them properly is always a better solution.

Comment: @xenoid Well, thank you for your help. I guess I have some work to do.

Answer (score 0):

If other people end up here, try:

**1. What @xenoid said**

> 1) Check that you can start these programs from a terminal and that they still run (they could have dependencies not resolved on the new system).
>
> 2) Create a `{application}.desktop` file for each of them (there must be an application menu editor somewhere in your system).

**2. If that fails**

Then try to reinstall you programs, installing may/may not be faster as you do have its files in your `/home` partition.

Feel free to add your own answer.